# GPU and dedicated running at the same time, how to disable?

Tags: windows, gpu, temperature, overheating, integrated-graphics

My laptop has issues with core temperatures that reach to 97 celcius(205 fahrenheit) sometimes.
So, i put my cpu to a stress test and with all cores at 100%, the temperature was only 65 degrees (149 fahrenheit).
So, i started to think that the problem is not the cpu, its the integrated gpu that is working with the cpu on games and increasing the temperatures so much.

so i installed afterburner to test it, and saw this:

[image: GPU and dedicated graphic full loading]

Why the integrated graphics is working togheter with the gpu?
is there any way to disable the gpu working together with dedicated?

my temperature issues is for this, how i enable my mx150 working alone without the integrated card?

My spec:
intel core i5 8250U
Directx 12
integrated: Intel UHD Graphics 620
Dedicated: Nvidia MX150

[image: i want to avoid this...]

Comment: What is a 97% temperature? Are you reporting degrees Fahrenheit or Centigrade?

Comment: Would you prefer to completely disable the integrated graphics and always use the dedicated?

Comment: Sorry, celcius.
I dont want to disable always my integrated because it will consume more batery power. I just want to disable in game or in applications that needs a graphic card (like unreal engine) .
My goal is disable integrated when dedicated is used

Comment: If that's the case, I would right click on the desktop and select NVIDIA Control Panel. From there you can select *Manage 3D settings* and then use the *Global Settings* or *Program Settings* tabs to decide if you want the computer to auto switch, use integrated, or use dedicated GPU for a specific program. Give that a shot and see if it's what you're looking for. Also, reply with @DrZoo so I get a notification about a comment you make.

Comment: Do note that on some systems, you may not be able to completely disable the integrated GPU because the dedicated one has no connection to the display outputs (what these systems actually do is render each frame on the dedicated GPU then copy it to the integrated GPU, using the integrated GPU as a frame-buffer).

Comment: How do you know "GPU 1" is the Intel integrated graphics?  Seems much more likely that GPU 0 is Intel and GPU 1 is nVidia.

Answer (score 1):

## It's by design and you should not disable integrated GPU.

99% of "hybrid graphics" solutions have integrated GPU hardwired to video outputs and a stripped down version of dedicated GPU that can render stuff, but has no outputs. When dedicated GPU is used, it draws in its memory and sends frames to integrated GPU to render. Without integrated GPU, the dedicated one wouldn't be able to display anything.

Comment: It's only the RAMDAC portion of the iGPU that is needed for this, the rest of it can and should be disabled. On the other hand, OP clearly has a problem with his cooling solution if hitting over 90 Celsius with 2.7W.